# tkinter run function in parent window when child window closes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a parent window in tkinter that opens a child window like this:

```
def openChild(data):
            callChildFunc(data,"y")

Button(dash, text="Open", command=partial(openChild, data))
```

This calls a function `callChildFunc(data,fill)` which takes input and saves it to a `json` file. The child window closes like this:

```
def getInput(file):
            #bunch of commands to save data from input fields...
            childform.destroy()

Button(childform, text="Save", command=partial(getInput, data))
```

I want to call a function in the parent window when the child window is destroyed. Is there any way for the parent window to detect when the child is destroyed, or a way to pass an argument from the destroyed window back to the parent?

Comment: please add proper formatting around your code blocks. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution that does what I want, execute a function when the child window is destroyed:

```
child.bind("<Destroy>",parentfunction())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a global variable, to which getInput could save it's data, and the parent window could then access afterwards.

If you don't mind rewriting your code, another way of doing it would be to use classes to manage your windows, and opening the child as a TopLevel widget ie.:

```
import tkinter as tk

class parent(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Open", command=lambda : self.openChild())
        # class variable for saving input of child
        self.data = None

    def openChild(self):
        self.child = tk.TopLevel()
        # entry box for data
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.child)
        # button for saving data
        button1 = tk.Button(self.child, text='Save', command= lambda : self.getInput())

    def getInput(self):
        if self.child:
            self.data = self.entry1.get()
            self.child.destroy()
```

Don't know if that's the most elegant way of handling that, but using classes gives you a lot more options for tkinter, it's worth a look.

Comment: This is helpful for getting data back to the parent. But I needed to cause a function to execute, and couldn't figure out how to do that with the data. I ended up using this: child.bind("<Destroy>",parentfunction())